# Next and previous buttons in carousel

Tags: javascript, jquery, carousel, owl-carousel

I am working on a [website](https://jsfiddle.net/97j9gmtm/656/embedded/result) in which I want to **hide next and previous buttons when there is only one image on the carousel** and **show next and previous buttons when there are multiple images**.

The php code which I have used which I have used in order to rendered multiple images at the front end are:

```
<div class="col-9 text-center border-right px-0">
   <div id="owl_item_images" class="owl-carousel owl-theme">
      <?php
         if(isset($data['item']->gallery))
         {
         foreach ($data['item']->gallery as $gallery)
         {
         echo '<div class="item">
         <div class="item_image_wrapper mx-auto">
         <img class="item_images_carousel" src="'.$gallery->url.'">
         </div>
         </div>';
         //'.$gallery->url.';
         }
         }
         ?>
   </div>
</div>
```

**Problem Statement:**

I am wondering what carousel code I need to add so that **next and previous buttons** show up when there are multiple images, and **no next and previous buttons** show up when there is single image.

**What I have tried:**

`<script>$('#owl_item_images').owlCarousel({nav : false});</script>` By using that, all images get visible (with images lining up side by side) inside the carousel.

I also tried with the following code:

`$('#owl_item_images').trigger('change.owl.carousel', { nav: true });` but it didn't work as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can count the number of images in the carousel using jQuery. Then, only show the nav if there is more than one image.

Try this:

```
<script>
var imageCount = $('#owl_item_images .item_images_carousel').length;
var showNav = false;
if (imageCount > 1) showNav = true;
$('#owl_item_images').owlCarousel({nav : showNav});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not tried it but this should do the trick:

```
if(size($data['item']->gallery)<=1)
{
   echo "<script>
          $(function(){
                $('#owl_item_images').owlCarousel({nav : false});
           });
         </script>";
}
```

put this after foreach loop

Answer (score 0):

If I am not missing something, what you asked for is pretty much out of the box. 
if you set `nav:true` owl.carousel itself will show navigation if there is more than one item, and no navigation if there is only one item, as seen in that pen:
https://codepen.io/optionsit/pen/BPGzvV

what version of owl.carousel are you using? and do you have anymore markup in your carousel?